# nmake v6 recursive build c files

Tags: c, recursion, build, nmake

I'm trying to get *nmake - version 6* to build a c-project recursively, thereby mitigating the painful single line rules for each source file and it's associated object.

See example below:

Currently this is what I have which works (snippet)...

```
File1 = aes
File2 = sha256     
File3 = pkcs5

$(ObjDir)\$(File1).o : $(SrcDir)\$(File1).c
  @echo Compiling  ... $(File1)
  @$(CC) -c $(Includes) $(CFLAGS) $(SrcDir)\$(File1).c

$(ObjDir)\$(File2).o : $(SrcDir)\$(File2).c
  @echo Compiling  ... $(File2)
  @$(CC) -c $(Includes) $(CFLAGS) $(SrcDir)\$(File2).c

$(ObjDir)\$(File3).o : $(SrcDir)\$(File3).c
  @echo Compiling  ... $(File3)
  @$(CC) -c $(Includes) $(CFLAGS) $(SrcDir)\$(File3).c
```

However, I'd prefer to do something like this (not working, no error thrown)...

```
$(ObjDir)\$(SrcDir:%|fF.c=%|fF.o): $(SrcDir)\%.c
    @echo Compiling ... $(*B)
    @$(CC) -c $(Includes) $(CFLAGS) $*.c
```

**Command references used:**
[Filename Macros]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa233975(v=vs.60).aspx 
[Filename-Parts Syntax]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa233961(v=vs.60).aspx
[Macro Substitution]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsd42ets.aspx

Thanks for your assistance in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For those who were probably working on a solution. I've figured out a way to achieve what I want. Please see my solution below:

```
OBJS=aes.o \
     sha256.o \
     pkcs5.o

$(OBJS):
  @echo Compiling $(*B).c ...
  $(CC) $(Includes) $(CFLAGS) $(SrcDir)\$(*B).c
```